# How should I use Perl's File::Temp?

Tags: perl, temporary-files

I would like to create a temp file,  write to the file-handle then call an external program with the filename.

The problem is I would normally want to `close` the file after writing to it and before calling the external program, but if I understand correctly `close`-ing a `tempfile()` causes it to be removed.

So what is the solution here?

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want a _temporary_ file.

Comment: but I do. I call the external program from within my script. After it's done, I don't need the file anymore.

Comment: Actually `File::Temp` does not unlink the file after creation (in contrast to `IO::File->new_tmpfile`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write to the temp file with buffering turned off. Call the external program before you close the file in the Perl script, and the external program will be able to read everything you have written.

```
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
use IO::Handle;

my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile( $template, ... );

... make some writes to $fh ...

# flush  but don't  close  $fh  before launching external command
$fh->flush;
system("/path/to/the/externalCommand --input $filename");

close $fh;
# file is erased when $fh goes out of scope
```

Comment: I have a uncontrollable repulsion from using open files... but this seems to work.

Comment: Where is `$template` defined and what is it defined to: not even the official docs for `File::Temp` make mention of this elusive piece of crap.

Comment: It is any string that [ends with](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/File-Temp-0.2304/lib/File/Temp.pm#L256) [4 or more consecutive `X`'s](https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/File-Temp-0.2304/lib/File/Temp.pm#L87)

Answer (score 6):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html:

```
unlink_on_destroy

Control whether the file is unlinked when the object goes out of scope. The file is removed if this value is true and $KEEP_ALL is not.

   1. $fh->unlink_on_destroy( 1 );

Default is for the file to be removed.
```

Try to set it to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

with OOP interface of `File::Temp` you can do:

```
my $cpp =  File::Temp->new;
print $cpp "SOME TEXT";
$cpp->flush;

`cat $cpp`;
```

Answer (score 0):

closing is better than flushing, because of possible deadlock. File::Temp tempfile is opened with lock

```
{
    my $tmp = File::Temp->new(
        UNLINK => 0
    );

    select $tmp;
    say 123;
    select STDOUT;

    # $tmp->flush;
    close $tmp;

    say 'slurp >> ', path($tmp->filename)->slurp;
}

{
    my $tmp = Path::Tiny->tempfile(
        UNLINK => 0
    );

    my $fh = $tmp->filehandle('+>');

    select $fh;
    say 123;
    select STDOUT;

    # $fh->flush;
    close $fh;

    say 'slurp >> ', $tmp->slurp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same scenario, here is what I found after some reading and experimenting:

```perl
my $XML;
# ...
if ($XML) {
    use File::Temp;
    my $tf = File::Temp->new('TEMPLATE' => 'monXXXXXX', 'DIR' => '/tmp',
                             'SUFFIX' => '.xml');

    $tf->print($XML);
    # in reality a more complex command than "cat" is being used
    $tf->close() and system(qw(/usr/bin/cat), $tf->filename());
    # ...
}
```

The point here is that using `$tf` after `close` to get the filename, prevents the file from being deleted (i.e.: `$tf` being garbage-collected and DESTROYed).
I don't need the temporary file any more after `system`, so it's OK if it's removed after that call.

I theory Perl could garbage-collect `$tf` immediately after the filename had been determined (and thus the external command would not find it any more), but that's not how Perl works.
If paranoid, you could pass `$tf` to some function after `system`, thus preventing garbage collection before...